# Avoid overlapping of the vertical line of arrow and '\path' label in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the following code to specify the length of a line:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [stealth-stealth](0,-0.8) -- (1,-0.8);
\draw [|-|](0,-0.8) -- (1,-0.8) ; 
\path (0,-0.85) -- (1,-0.85) node [midway, above] {$B$ = 10};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

As apparent from the image the vertical lines of the arrow and 'B' and '10' are overlapping. How to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried with `above=1mm` ? (adjust to taste)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `quotes` library is simple ...

**Edit:**
If arrow style `LM` in document is used frequently, than is sensible to move its definition to preamble. See corrected MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                quotes}

\tikzset{
LM/.style = {very thin,
        {Bar[]Stealth}-%
        {Stealth[]Bar}
            },
% other common sty definitions like
every edge quotes/.append style= {font=\footnotesize}
        }


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [LM] (0,0) to ["$B=10$"] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Zarko, can you please tell how to globally define the command `LM/.style = {very thin,{Bar[]Stealth}-%{Stealth[]Bar}},` . I have to use this at a lot of places. Hence, including it all these places is cumbersome and make the code a bit cluttered.

Comment: @Aim, just mode this definition to preamble, in `tikzset`. For example `\tikzset{
LM/.style = {very thin,
        {Bar[]Stealth}-%
        {Stealth[]Bar}
            },
        }`. See edited answer.

Comment: @ Zarko, the additional command `every edge quotes/.append style= {font=\footnotesize}` makes `$B=10$` look elegant. Can you please tell how to apply the same fontsize even to nodes? For e.g. to `$c$`  in `\node at (1,1) {$c$};`? I tried `every edge/.append style={nodes={ font=\footnotesize}}`. But, it is not working.

Comment: @Aim, you can replace `every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize}}` with `every node/.append style ={font=\footnotesize}}`, however, people like to have bigger fonts in nodes than in edge quotes or labels. So you my consider just add into `\tikzset` for example `every node/.append style= {font=\small}`

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion:

1. use an explicit `above` distance;
2. use the `arrows.meta` library (`arrows` is deprecated) to join the two tips;
3. you can use just one path:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mark/.tip={Stealth[sep=-0.4pt] Bar }]
    \draw [mark-mark](0,-0.8) -- (1,-0.8) node [midway, above=1mm] {$B$ = 10};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A `dimline` has the advantage of providing a uniform style for exactly that.

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\dimline[extension start length=0 cm, extension end length=0 cm,label style={above=0.5ex}] { (0,-0.85)} {(1,-0.85)}{$B = 10$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Dimensionline with description]